# New intent, how to link to my class?

Tags: android, view, android-intent

I'm beginner in Android (and java), and I'm just playing around and want to create new View after clicking a button. Here is my code so far:

**Main class**

```
package myTests.homeSpace;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TestsActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(TestsActivity.this, screen1.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Class to run after clicking button**

```
package myTests.homeSpace;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class screen1 extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedBundleInstance)
    {
        super.onCreate(SavedBundleInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen1);
    }
}
```

The problem is, after hitting button I got "Unforunately, Tests has stopped" error. ("Tests" is application name). I know (or guess) the problem is in this line `Intent myIntent = new Intent(TestsActivity.this, screen1.class);` 
I guess my reference to class `screen1` is wrong somehow, but I have no idea why. There are no compilation errors nor warnings, layout .xmls shouldn't be wrong.

Could any of you please advice me any solution?

**EDIT**

**MANIFEST**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myTests.homeSpace"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TestsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT**

```
[2012-06-20 19:56:21 - ddms] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:575)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:672)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

Comment: Can you post your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, as well as the LogCat errors? (You can find the latter in Eclipse.) It's likely you haven't declared the Activity yet.

Comment: You might have forgotten to declare the `screen1` activity in the manifest file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, not declaring the activity in your Manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml) is most likely your problem. See the android developer [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) on activities for more information. Here is the relevant description:

> Declares an activity (an Activity subclass) that implements part of
>   the application's visual user interface. All activities must be
>   represented by  elements in the  manifest file. Any that are
>   not declared there will not be seen by the system and will never be
>   run.

I just posted this so you would have more space to research on your own.

Answer (score 4):

I bet if you read the *crash log* somewhere in there says *did you forget to declare this activity in the Manifest?*

Answer (score 0):

Declare your second activity in the Manifest.xml as:

```
<activity
        android:name=".screen1">
    </activity>
```

Just below the declaration of your first activity.